# Explode Binary value column

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-storage, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to explode or flatten a column "Body" which is of binary data type. 
 After converting Column Body into string, data is viewed in the below format

```
{
 "header" :
 {
 "name" : "XYZ", 
 "company" : "ABC"
 }
"payload" :
{
"salary": '"1234"
}
}
```

I am looking in the below tabular format

name,company,salary

I have tried to explode but it threw an error as it is a binary but when I tried to convert to string, it again threw an error like string data type cannot be exploded

```
val sample = udf((Body: Array[Byte]) => new String(Body))
val df2 = myDF.withColumn("TMP1", sample(myDF("Body"))).drop("Body")
```

Could you please suggest a possible solution for the above issue?